# Asp.Net MVC 3 - Linq To Entities - PK with Null doesn't get inserted into the db (don't want null :))

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, exception, linq-to-entities, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using the latest Asp.Net MVC version.

For some reason, when my POST (Action Create) in my controller gets hit.
I can't seem to be able to add it to the entityset.

What i have is,

1) My EntityModel (*.edmx file)

2) Controller which references the entity:

```
     private db.DataContainer _db = new db.DataContainer();
```

3) My method (i'm using Guid as pk):

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Client client)
    {
        try
        {
            client.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

            /* method 2
            Client cl = new Client();
            cl.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            cl.email = client.email;
            cl.Adres = client.Adres;
            cl.companyName = client.companyName;
            cl.fax = client.fax;
            cl.phone = client.phone;
            */
            //    client.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            _db.ClientSet.AddObject(client);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var ex_message = ex.Message;
            var ex_data = ex.Data;
            var ex_ix = ex.InnerException;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

4) Following is my InnerException:

```
 [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException] = {"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'lst.dbo.ClientSet'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

Both doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Change StoreGeneratedPattern to None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that changing my "saveCommand" has given my a temporarily solution:
I chaned:

```
_db.SaveChanges()
```

To

```
_db.SaveChanges(System.Data.Objects.SaveOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

GUIDs are not supported as primary keys in the Entity Framework. You will need to modify your save method to generate a new GUID for your added objects http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283139.aspx

Comment: False.

"The Entity Framework supports server-generated GUID type identity values, but the provider must be able to return the server-generated identity value after a row is inserted. SQL Server can return the server-generated GUID type through the OUTPUT clause starting with SQL Server 2005."